# Send request header from Varnish to backend server

Tags: varnish

Is it at all possible to send some headers from varnish end to backend server during a fetch? I need this to identify a certain scenario in my backend.

Which subroutine should I use and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom backend request headers in the `vcl_backend_fetch` subroutine.

Here's an example:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80;
}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    set bereq.http.my-custom-header = "my-custom-value";
}
```

Keep in mind that `vcl_backend_fetch` is backend-side subroutine that uses the `bereq` object to obtain client request information.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-configuration-language-vcl/#backend-request-variables for more information about backend request variables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried that.  But my PHP backend was not able to get this request header using `apache_request_headers()`. That's why I thought I might be doing something wrong. In the mean time, I succeeded in getting the header in the backend when I sent the same in `vcl_recv` using `set req.http.X-my-custom-header = "my-custom-value";` Is there a reason why? Sorry I am not very conversant in Varnish.

Comment: @PratipGhosh I just tested it myself with an Apache/PHP setup and `apache_request_headers()` did successfully return the `X-my-custom-header` header. It probably has nothing to do with VCL. It's either related to how Varnish is connected to Apache or how PHP is configured.